# Multiple Tables

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm running a test in Cucumber where a table with ID `clickable-rows`. My test result is telling me that there is an ambiguous match when navigating to this table, yet running an xpath check via F12 shows the table is only there once.

Is there a way I can say to search within the first table found? Until my dev's can sort this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will find the first table and then you can find within it

```
first_table = page.find(:xpath, './/table[1]')
first_table.find(...)
```

Comment: Ahhh, why didn't I think of that?!?!  Thank you